# YouTube API Browser-based upload with progress bar

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, cors

I have implemented "YouTube API Browser-Based Upload with Ajax Progress Bar" successfully (Thanks to the recent implementation of CORS support for "uploads.gdata.youtube.com" by the youtube API Team)

However, there is a snag... In the final response back from the youtube API, it attempts to redirect the browser, by sending back a location redirect header (302)...

While this might work as expected under non-AJAX scenarios, it is not permissible in an AJAX request...

I see 3 possible solutions to the problem, any one of which would work fine...

1. It would just be much much more simpler and easier for everyone, if youtube API allowed for a way to simply get back the "video ID" of the just uploaded video, without having to redirect anywhere... IS there any such option in the API that I have overlooked?
2. OR is there a way in AJAX, to tell the request, NOT TO FOLLOW the redirect header?
3. OR is there any way, by which I could "Allow" the cross-domain redirections within the AJAX request scenario? (Redirect is being initiated by youtube.com, while the user is on another domain, hence the cross-domain redirection issue)

Comment: The following sample might help: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html#60

Comment: Thanks for the link, but its not what I am looking for... I am looking to upload the file via AJAX (which actually I am able to accomplish). The problem is with the response that I get back from youtube, which is a redirect response, instead of some JSON/HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be supported for v1/v2 of the GData API.

For the YouTube Data API v3, I've got a rough, but working, example at https://youtube-api-samples.googlecode.com/git/yt-upload-javascript/index.html (source files at https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git%2Fyt-upload-javascript) that shows the upload flow, using the Google+ sign-in button to handle OAuth 2 (you can use the normal OAuth 2 browser client flow if you'd prefer) and with a progress indicator. It also shows how you could poll for video processing status following an upload and embed the resulting video on a page once it's been processed.

Answer (score 0):

That's a known [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4050) which is supposed to be fixed but actually it's not fixed. The browser based upload method (which is available on V2 only ) doesn't fully support CORS. Your only option is to either proxy the video upload through your server(most likely)  or ask the user to sign up for a google account and login to upload the video using the V3 API (not nice) .